# Wolfram Language Server(vscode extension) don't wok

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

**Environment:**

- Wolfram Language Server Extension v0.1.11
- Wolfram Engine 14.0
- lsp-wl 0.3/0.2
- needed paclets installed (CodeParser, CodeInspector)
- wolfram server path and wolfram.exe path correctly set
- a lauch.json file :

```
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "dap-wl",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Create a new Wolfram Kernel"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output:**

```
[INFO  2024-03-07T19:28:32] Initializing Wolfram Language Server
[INFO  2024-03-07T19:28:36] Language server is connecting the client through
socket.
[INFO  2024-03-07T19:28:36] Server listening from port 6536...
```

**Problem:**
It seems like I had been connecting to the server, but I don't see any highlight in my vscode editor, and no intelligence, I cannot even run my code, when I try to run, I get message:

`connect ECONNREFUSED127.0.0.1:<port>`

when I use wolfram.exe to run the XX.wls directly, it runs normally.
So I wonder if there is any thing I miss, I go through instructions like this https://gitee.com/wei_hong_liang/vscode-lsp-wl, over and over again, but still don't know why.

I did try to use lower version of wolfram engines, but there is a lot of mistakes, then I try to use a lower version of lsp-wl and extension as well, but still having mistakes, so I switch to Wolfram Engine14.0
Does anyone know why?